# Unsigned Integer Literal Having Negative Sign

Tags: c#, int

Today I came a cross this strange behaviour, could someone explain why it happens?

```
var x = -1U; // When using -1UL it complains though.
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Output:

> Int64
>
> -1

MSDN says:

> If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: You can't convert a `negative value` to an `unsigned int/long`.

Comment: I guess you are asking why it isn't throwing compile time error?

Comment: `var x = unchecked((ulong)-1);` this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion stems from you interpreting this as the number `-1`, followed by a suffix `U`. It's actually the negation `-` of the number `1U`. That number `1U` has type `uint`, as indicated by the quote in your question. Negating an `uint` produces a `long`.

Comment: `var x = -1UL;` 
If your thoughts are right, why in this situation compile-time exception is thrown ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan Because `1UL` is a `ulong`, and you cannot negate a `ulong`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is using `unary operator -` and as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691145(v=vs.71).aspx

> For the unary - operator, the operand is converted to type T, where T is the first of int and long that can fully represent all possible values of the operand. The operation is then performed using the precision of type T, and the type of the result is T. The unary - operator cannot be applied to operands of type ulong.

If i do something like

```
   var x =-1UL;
```

i get a compiler error `Operator '-' cannot be applied to operand of type 'ulong` It's because i am using unary operator

Whereas If i do

```
 var x =2UL-1UL;
```

The compiler doesnt complain because I am now using  `binary operator`

When you do `var x=-1UL` the compiler interprets it as `var x=0UL-1UL` which if say succeded will produce `-1UL` however if you take a look at the range of UL it is  `0 and 18446744073709551615` so `-1UL` is outside it's range hence the compile time error. same can be done for `ushort`  as well.

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't working for `ulong` too ? What is difference ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan there is no wider signed type that it can automatically convert to, as it does with uint -> long

Answer (score 0):

On this line of code you ask compiler to choose type by using an implicit type `var`, then you assign a negative value to it by using this `-` sign :

```
var x = -1U; // it is converted to simple -1
```

So it's converted by compiler to `-1` and it finds closest type with range corresponding to `uint`s range and which can work with negative values  - `long`

```
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);  // displays long (Int64)
Console.WriteLine(x);                 // displays -1
```

As been said you can use `unchecked` keyword to let compile know that it should not perform overflow-checking . A quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) :

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

So this should compile and run and x will be of type `ulong` :

```
// UInt64 here
    var x = unchecked((ulong)-1);
```